# Probability of batter getting fewer than 200 hits

Tags: probability, statistics

A certain baseball player has a batting average $p=0.2$ (meaning
that the chance of a hit is $0.2$ in each at-bat). Show that the
probability of the player getting fewer than $200$ hits in his next $900$
at-bats is approximately $0.95$.
Hint: $\frac{18}{12} \neq \frac{1}{5}$ and $ \frac{0.5}{12} \neq 0.04$

I'm really confused about how to approach this problem. Any help?

Comment: $\frac{18}{12} \neq \frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{0.5}{12} \neq 0.04$. What do you mean for the hint?

Comment: every hit is an independent event?

Comment: You need to use the [normal approximation](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~campbell/stat/prob8.html) to do this (or a computer).  My hint would be that the mean is $\mu = 0.200 * 900 = 180$ and the variance is $\sigma = 900 * 0.2 * 0.8 = 144$ which means the standard deviation is $\delta = 12$.

Comment: @MonkeyKing Hmm, you're right, that is just what was given as a hint. I guess it is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

We have a Bernoulli distribution $X \sim Be(0.2)$

As @Jared pointed out, we have that the mean is $\mu = 180$, variance is  $\sigma ^2 = 144$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 12$.

Let's be $Y$ the variable that measures the number of hits after 900 hits.
Using normal distribution and Central Limit Theorem we have that $P(Y<200) \sim P(Z< \frac {200-\mu}{\sigma})=P(Z<\frac {20}{12})\approx 0.95$

Comment: duly noted about the notation...wasn't sure if that was right or not.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting between 0 and 199 hits out of 900 at bats, with a probability of 0.2 per at bat is going to be

$$\sum_{i=0}^{199} \binom{900}{i}{.2^i(1-.2)^{900-i}}$$

This is the sum of the probabilities of getting each number of hits from 0 to 199

If you enter this into Wolfram Alpha:
summation(binomial(900, j))*(0.2^j)*((1-0.2)^(900-j)) from 0 to 199

The result is 0.95 to two decimal points.